# ContextConfiguration does not seem to load my beans for TestNg testcase

Tags: spring, maven, testng

I am new to TestNg. I am trying to test one sample hello world program. 
Following is my project structure

Source Package

- com.mycompany.mavenproject1 =>HelloWorld.java

Test Package

- com.test =>  NewTestConfig.java & NewTestNGTest.java

Helloworld.java

```
package com.mycompany.mavenproject1;
public class HelloWorld {
  String msg = "test";

  public String getMsg() {
    return msg;
  }
  public void setMsg(String msg) {
    this.msg = msg;
  }
}
```

NewTestConfig.java

```
package com.test;
import com.mycompany.mavenproject1.HelloWorld;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
@Configuration
public class NewTestConfig {
     @Bean
    public HelloWorld helloWorldBean() {
        HelloWorld hw = new HelloWorld();
        return hw;
    }
}
```

NewTestNGTest.java

```
package com.test;

import com.mycompany.mavenproject1.HelloWorld;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;

@Test
@ContextConfiguration(classes={ NewTestConfig.class })
public class NewTestNGTest {
   @Autowired
    HelloWorld hw ;

    @Test
    public void exampleOfTestNgMaven() {
        String s = hw.getMsg();        
        System.out.println("This is TestNG-Maven Example" + s);
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUpMethod() throws Exception {
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDownMethod() throws Exception {
    }    
}
```

My pom.xml looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>mavenproject1</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

When I try to run the test I get NullpointerException (at hw.getMsg();)

### Error stack:

### Test set: com.test.NewTestNGTest

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.209 sec <<< FAILURE!
exampleOfTestNgMaven(com.test.NewTestNGTest)  Time elapsed: 0.003 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.NewTestNGTest.exampleOfTestNgMaven(NewTestNGTest.java:25)

I tried to run test in debug mode, I always get HelloWorld bean as null. So eventually test fails due to NullPointerException. I tried many other variations such as instead of config class tried using applicationContext.xml but my bean never gets injected.

For last 2 days I am struggling to make simple test pass but unable to  figure out what's going wrong. Why my context is not getting loaded for test?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Manisha

Comment: You should extend one of the Spring TestNg base classes currently nothing is done with the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation as it is just a plain TestNG test.

Comment: What maven command did you used to run?

Comment: Please read http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#testcontext-support-classes-testng.

Comment: Thanks a lot! 'extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests' solved my problem.